# Issue updating modal with Slack views.update endpoint

Tags: slack-api

When trying to update my modal using Slack's views.update endpoint, I get an "error": "not found" message in the return body.

According to Slack's documentation, this means that the view ID or external ID could not be found, but I've made sure to check the initial view ID to make sure it matches and I've tried generating unique external IDs to ensure that the correct modal is being referenced.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried by inserting value in the testing portion, https://api.slack.com/methods/views.update/test

Comment: Did you find a solution? Stuck with the same problem.